# Mocking a collection.find method

Tags: java, mongodb, junit, mockito

I have method that is calling mongodb collection to get a list. I want to mock the outcome of the list but i am getting NPE on it.

```
public String convertId(String Id, int counter) {
    String id2 = "test";
    List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
    collection.find(eq(id,id2)).into(objectList);
    Object obj = objectList.get(0);
    return obj.getId();
}
```

I am getting null pointer on collection.find method. The test case is wrote is :

```
@Test
public void convertIdTest() {
    List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
    Document doc1 = new Document();
    Mockito.when(collection.find(Mockito.any(BasicDBObject.class))).thenReturn(iterable);
    Mockito.when(iterable.iterator()).thenReturn(cursor);
    Mockito.when(cursor.hasNext()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
    Mockito.when(cursor.next).thenReturn(doc1);
    assertNotNull(request.converId("1233",1);
}
```

≈========≈========================

iterable is of type:

```
FindIterable<Object> iterable = mock(FindIterable.class)
MongoCursor cursor = mock(MongoCursor.class)
```

Comment: Show us how are you creating your collection instance

Comment: @Mock MongoCollection<Object> collection is what i am using.